# How to send JSON to front-end without fetch based on params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, nodejs-server

I am trying to make an express template that displays a post based on the URL / params. Similar to what we have on StackOverflow (I have topic instead of questions + id):
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111111/`
and I have:
`localhost:8003/act/random/111111/`

authController.act requests and returns post data from MySQL. This is my route:

```
router.get('/act/:topic/:id/:title?', authController.isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {

  const promise = authController.act(req.params.topic, req.params.id);
  promise.then((results) => {
    res.render('act', {
      message1: 'some message', results: results
    });
  });

});
```

And than I want to use it in my HTML/EJS file:

```
<body onload="init();loadAct(results)">
```

My results get successfully passed to the EJS file and can be used like this `<%- results %>` as suggested by Kapil Sharma. Now I need to figure out why it won't work in JS.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: results is not defined
    onload http://localhost:8003/act/random/127/:1
```

Edit:
This seems to solve my problem. Quentin also proposed a second solution below if this doesn't help.

```
<body onload="init();loadAct(JSON.parse('<%= JSON.stringify(results) %>'));" >
```

Comment: res.json() will not be able to render HTML. Did you try printing in your EJS <% console.log(results) %> or printing it like <p><%- results %></p>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does actually work like that. It seems that I have a problem passing from EJS to JS in the onload.

Comment: The JavaScript program that *runs on the server via the EJS template processor* and the completely different JavaScript program that *runs in the browser via the `onload` attribute* are completely different JavaScript programs. They don't share variables.

Comment: @Nik You must get the value inside the <script> tag. Like, let data = `<%-results%>`. Use backtick <%-results%> backtick

Comment: @Quentin Ty for the input. I also found that this works: `loadAct(JSON.parse('<%= JSON.stringify(results) %>'));`